# ListView: intercept click event to adjust selector

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a ListView with my own adapter, who uses a own layout.

It's basically a horizontal `LinearLayout` with an Image and a TextView

I have specified a selector for my ListView, which changes the background color.

Furthermore I want to apply a ImageColorFilter on the ImageView. If the background changes.

Is there a simple way to do it with the build in ListView selector behavior or must I attach my own `OnTouchListener` to my LinearLayout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there are two possibilities:

1. Disbale the ListView selector and write your own OnTouchListener and
   handle the touch events.
2. Use `android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"` to draw the selector on top of your View instead of drawing in the background.